# Escaping a comma when uploading a .csv to a database with PHP

Tags: php, csv, escaping

I'm trying to do a simple PHP function to put a .csv file into a database. The problem is that the files are delimited with a semicolon and for some reason when a cell contains a comma it leaves out everything after it.

For example the .csv file

```
manufacturer;comment;year
toyota;good car, bad color;1997
```

comes out as the following when printed with the `print_r()` function

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => manufacturer
    [1] => comment
    [2] => year
)

[1] => Array
(
    [0] => toyota
    [1] => good car
)
```

#### Edit

Here's the code I'm using.

```
//get the contents of the .csv file     
$filepath = './files/csvfile.csv'
$fileopen = fopen($filepath,"r");
//create an empty array
$csv = array();
//go through the .csv file with fgetcsv()
while(($line = fgetcsv($fileopen,";")) !== FALSE)
{

    $line =  explode(";",$line[0]);


    $csv[] = $line;
}

    //print the result
    echo "<pre>";
            print_r($csv);
    echo "</pre>";
fclose($fileopen);
```

Comment: If you're using getcsv() then you shouldn't have any problem, but perhaps if you show your code we might see what you're doing wrong

Comment: Added the code to the question. Its probably formatted wrong so feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the delimiter as the 3rd argument

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($fileopen, 0, ";")) !== FALSE)
```

I don't think you need that explode line either.